# Chrome DevTools (inspect devices) opened with blank tabs

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I can detech and inspect the App into the Android emulator, it always worked fine, until few days.
The most of the tabs are completly blank, and also the console is KO.
I can see only the 'Memory', 'Application'.
I have update Chrome to the last version and I have also 'Restored defaults and reload' from the settings of DevTools.
The next image shows the situation.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug in new Chrome. Try an older portable Chrome.

Comment: this behavior was present before the update that I done, and is not related to the chrome updates I suppose

Comment: Still looks like a bug.

Comment: using the previous version (79.0.3945.88), it works